# PHP - access values inside a json response

Tags: php, json

I have a requirement to access value inside an object return from an API response in PHP. 
API response

```
$res = {
    "data": {
        "first_name": "Dany",
        "last_name": "mate",
        "id": "1379933133290837510",
        "image": {
            "60x60": {
                "url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/dtest_1438666564_60.jpg",
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to access the parameters "first_name" & "url"? Your help is much appreciated. I have tried to convert the response in to an array but not worked

```
$array = get_object_vars($res);
```

I don't know is it the correct way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be JSON to me, did you try `json_decode()`?

Comment: What is the exact response? This looks like a combination of php and js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = json_decode('{
    "data": {
        "first_name": "Dany",
        "last_name": "mate",
        "id": "1379933133290837510",
        "image": {
            "60x60": {
                "url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/dtest_1438666564_60.jpg",
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            }
        }
    }
}');
$array = get_object_vars($res);
print_r($array);
```

you need to utilize `json_decode` for doing that.

Comment: instead of using `get_object_vars()` you could simply use `json_decode($string, true);`. This returns an array instead of an object.

Comment: Thank you @ameenulla0007

Answer (score 1):

You have to json decode first:

```
$json = json_decode($res,true);

foreach ($json['data'] as $data)
{
    echo $data['first_name'];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $pp = json_decode('{
    "data": {
        "first_name": "Dany",
        "last_name": "mate",
        "id": "1379933133290837510",
        "image": {
            "60x60": {
                "url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/dtest_1438666564_60.jpg",
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            }
        }
    }
}');
 $data = json_encode($pp->{'data'});

  $aa = json_decode($data);
  echo $aa->{'first_name'} .'  & ';

  $image = json_encode($aa->{'image'});
  $dd = json_decode($image);

  $sity = json_encode($dd->{'60x60'});
  $url = json_decode($sity);
  echo $url->{'url'};
?>
```